# Opened windows switching back to My Computer when USB unplugged on windows 10 OS

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb, pen

Whenever I unplug my USB pen drive all my other opened windows in windows 10 and windows 11 OS are switched to My Computer and Desktop folder respectively. I didn't find a solution for this issue. How do I solve this problem?
[image]
It is supposed that all the opened windows must be the same as it is whenever the pen drive is unplugged. But whenever I unplug the pen drive, all my other windows switch to My Computer. Can anyone help me find the problem?
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that these windows are not open to ghdroot if subfolder of the drive?  Also, i f you have a shortcut to the drive, it may be closing all windows.

Comment: @RohitGupta I have two windows open that is My FIles and My Documents. Then I plugged pen drive and done some copy and then unplugged by clicking safely remove and suddenly all the above said two folders become My Computer and shows all our C D E... partitions. I don't created any shortcuts or anything.

Comment: @RohitGupta Is this issue is caused by using same OS in two laptops. I have a purchased OS that have been installed on two laptops. Any idea?